# How to extract zipped archive hidden behind an image file?

Tags: compression, zip, archiving, winrar

I **zipped** few files using **winRAR** and hide those behind an image file using the following command :

```
Copy /b imagename.jpg + filename.rar finalimage.jpg
```

The operation was successful, however the resultant file is corrupted as when I try to open it with winRAR so that I can extract the hidden files it shows following error :

[image: Error: The archive is either in unknown format or damaged]

I tried recovering it using winRAR but it didn't worked. Is there any other way to somehow rebuild those images?
The files basically are zipped images.

Comment: cut the rar (or zip?) file from the size of imagename.jpg, then you'll get back the original archive file.

Comment: How do I cut the file ?

Comment: Open the file in HxD and copy everything that occurs from the bit that begins "Rar!" onward. Save that – including the "Rar!" – as a new file.